# HTML Elements whose parent elements are transparent won't go opaque

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to make an element whose parent is transparent opaque? For example, on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasperarmstrong/wqwfQ/), I have the word "blah" with a parent div that is transparent. How would I get "blah" to become opaque?

my html:

```
<div><p class="blah">blah</p></div>
```

my css:

```
div{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:white;
    opacity:0.5;
}
.blah{
    opacity:1;
}
body{
    background-color:blue;    
}
```

Comment: if the parent is set to opacity:0.5 all child elements are getting the same opacity.This is a bug in css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Children can't have a higher opacity than their parents as their opacities multiply.

You use could png backgrounds or rgba colors:
http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

```
div {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

opacity does not apply to "an element", it applies to "an element's and all of its content". You can make content more transparent than its parent, but not more opaque.